# Algorithm on finding all 4 letter words in a string - where's the last item?

Tags: swift, algorithm, loops

Posting a question here as *~find all ~4 letter words in a string ~algorithm site:stackoverflow.com* google did not return any positive results.

**The problem:**
Write a function that takes a string of words and returns the number of 4 letter ones. The input argument 'sentence' is a string with words separated by spaces without punctuation.

**So far I have a code like this:**

```
func fourLetters(sentence: String) -> Int {
    var targetNames = 0
    var letterCount = 0

    for letter in sentence {

    if letter != " " {
      letterCount += 1
      } else {
        print ("space found") // tech line
        print (letterCount) // tech line

        if letterCount == 4 {
          targetNames += 1
          letterCount = 0
          }
        letterCount = 0
      }
    }

    print(targetNames) // tech line
    return targetNames
}
```

**The issue:**
This algorithm now does not take into account the last part of the string giving the invalid number of 4 letter words. Consider we have the sentence: "Good Night Lil Peep" would return 1, although there are obviously two 4 teller words. What am I missing? Seems like the loop completely ignores the last word.

repl.it link for convenience and runs: https://repl.it/@DmitryAksyonov/4-lettered-names

Thank you for the help!
Regards

Comment: I think codereview.stackexchange.com is the right place for this question.

Comment: @KeshuR.: No, Code Review is for the reviewing (and improving) code that *“**works correctly,** to the best of the author's knowledge.”*

Comment: A one-liner: `return sentence.split(separator: " ").filter { $0.count == 4 }.count`

Comment: @MartinR I was about to comment that `sentence.split{$0.isWhitespace}.filter{$0.count == 4}.count"
`

Comment: @LeoDabus: And we are still waiting for `count(where:)` ... :)

Comment: @Dmitry: Xcode comes with a decent *debugger.* Set a breakpoint, single-step, inspect variables. You should see quickly where your code fails. – (Debugging is an *art* that every programmer *must* learn.)

Comment: @LeoDabus: And in Swift 5.2 you can do `split(whereSeparator: \.isWhitespace)` :)

Comment: @MartinR Never seen that. A possible count where implementation `extension Sequence {
    func count(where predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Int {
        reduce(into: 0) { $0 += predicate($1) ? 1 : 0 }
    }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus: That's https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md. – And `count(where:)` is here https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md, it has been accepted, but for some technical reasons not yet implemented in Swift: https://forums.swift.org/t/accepted-se-0220-count-where/15280/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func findWords(ofLenght lenght: Int, in string: String) -> [Substring] {
    let words = string.split{ $0.isWhitespace }
    return words.filter { $0.count == lenght }
}

let input = "abcd word some string"
let result = findWords(ofLenght: 4, in: input)
print(result.count)
```

> Output: 3

Comment: better to use `Character` property `isWhitespace`

Comment: It should print 3

Comment: No need to initialize a new string for every word. You can return an array of Substrings

Comment: Expanding on that I would make the method generic, constrain the generic type to `StringProtocol` and return an array os `SubSequence` but in that case OP just wants the count property of the resulting array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the incrementation code for `targetNames` is encountered only if you find a `space` in the input string, which is not the case at the end of the string. You may be lucky if the last character of the string is a `space`.

So your code will fail even in the case where your sentence contains just one 4-letter word.

A possible solution is that you modify the condition of your first `if` statement by adding another condition to it which returns false if the loop has reached the end of the string, so that the `else` part of your code will run at that time and check if that last word is a 4-letter word.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm doesn’t work because you don’t check for a 4-letter word at the end of the text.

You have to add another `else` clause and an index to check for *end of text*.

Of course there are more efficient ways to do that, it's just the answer to the question why the last item is not considered.

```
func fourLetters(sentence: String) -> Int {
    var targetNames = 0
    var letterCount = 0
    var index = sentence.startIndex

    for character in sentence {
        sentence.formIndex(after: &index)
        if character == " " { // check space
            print ("space found") // tech line
            print (letterCount) // tech line

            if letterCount == 4 {
                targetNames += 1
            }
            letterCount = 0
        } else if index == sentence.endIndex { // check end of text
            print ("end of text found") // tech line
            letterCount += 1 // increment letterCount
            if letterCount == 4 {
                targetNames += 1
            }
        } else {
            letterCount += 1
        }
    }
    print(targetNames) // tech line
    return targetNames
}

fourLetters(sentence: "Good Night Lil Peep") // 2
```

Comment: Another option would be to do a final check for `letterCount == 4` after the loop (makes the loop shorter and simpler).